# React-Redux best practice - Is it OK to return data from dispatch functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've googled around and couldn't find anything definitive relating to my question so thought i'd just ask here.

I'm fairly new to react and redux so go easy on me.

Lets say I have this bit of code.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props
    .getUnitData(this.props.match.params.unit_code)
    .then(unit => this.setState({ unit, loading: false, success: true }))
    .catch(() => this.setState({ loading: false, success: false }));
  }

  //redux action
  export const getUnitData = unitCode => dispatch =>
    api.units.getUnitData(unitCode).then(unit => {
    dispatch(unitDataReceived(unit));
    return unit;
  });
```

Is it OK to add a return statement to the redux action that returns an object (*unit* in this case) and setState with it after the Promise returns?

OR should I be using mapStateToProps, and then use componentWillReceiveProps() to setState()?

Obviously the first way seems a lot simpler. But at the same time if you're not planning to use the *unit* data in other components, it kinda makes the whole purpose of dispatching redundant, which obviously doesn't feel right.

Example of the second way for clarity.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props
      .getUnitData(this.props.match.params.unit_code)
      .then(() => this.setState({ loading: false, success: true }))
      .catch(() => this.setState({ loading: false, success: false }));
  }

  //redux action
  export const getUnitData = unitCode => dispatch =>
      api.units.getUnitData(unitCode).then(unit => {
      dispatch(unitDataReceived(unit));
  });

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      unit: state.unit
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.unit !== this.state.unit) {
      this.setState((unit: nextProps.unit));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we are in gray area. But if we are to take another prespective to your requirements, the fetched data is only consumed by a component (kept in state) and not shared. For just this purpose the first approach is fine. You can call the the api code directly in react component, better in componentwillmount. And remove the action, redux only requires to keep data that needs to be shared.

On the other if ever if it need to be shared, the second approach is best. An added bonus, if the data only need to be fetched once and thereafter reused, it can be cached. It can remain in the redux state. Components can spawn and die as the situation presents, data will retain, even though multiple user sessions, judging by the type of data.

Comment: It is not better to make API calls in `componentWillMount`, the docs as well recommend `componnetDidMount`. On top of that new versions of react will deprecate `componentWillMount` so it's better to get familiar with the good practices from now.

Comment: Thank you @G4bri3l, I didn't knew the apis are updating.

Comment: They have been talking about it for a while but just for reference here is a useful link: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes

Answer (score 1):

Here is my humble opinion. You are mixing your logic up and when in doubt I always suggest to pick an approach and stick with it across your app (yes there can be exceptions).

What I'm trying to say is that your decision should be based on where the data retrieved is consumed. If such data should be available on other components too then you might as well not set state locally and update the store. Then your components will simply "listen" to changes of that part of the store and update accordingly. Dispatching an action just for the sake of it but then using local state is kind of confusing. If you think about the Flux architecture you are emitting an event that does nothing, but then you are actually updating the local state.

On the other hand if this behavior is very well contained within this component only, then you don't need to dispatch an action at all and just handle everything within your component. I would avoid mixing things up as it could be confusing. Future you could come back to the code maybe check the redux devtools and notice that an action is dispatched, but then the store is never updated, why is that ? Is there an error somewhere ? Did I not pass any data back to the store from the action ? Am I reading the wrong fields from the action dispatched ?

Everything should be as straightforward as it can be, either:

`dispatch an action` => `update the store` => `component updates based on new store`

(there is a little more to it but I am simplifying).

One pattern that I sometime see is the one that has `thunks` return a `Promise`. So you normally use a thunk and dispatch an action and so on, but you return a `Promise` so that you can do some extra logic right after your asynch action has been dispatched. There are some use cases for it but I am not going to get into too many details now. I hope this helped somehow clarify things but if you have any other question let me know in the comments!